# AWS Cloud Directory list all object children pages

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, active-directory

I am working on an AWS Cloud Directory and want to list every children of an object with the `listObjectChildren` function.

But the thing is I cannot set the `MaxResults` parameter higher than 30 and don't really understand how to use the pagination token.

This is how I prepare my call :

```
let paramsChildren = {
    MaxResults: 30,
    DirectoryArn: directory_arn,
    ObjectReference: {
        Selector: objectPath
    }
}

clouddirectory.listObjectChildren(paramsChildren, function (err, data) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else res.send(data);
})
```

Is there any way that I could get every children in only one call ?

Answer (score 0):

I Found out that we just have to specify in the query parameters :

```
NextToken: nextToken
```

So I can loop while there is a next token provided in the response to fetch all children elements